# How to add different directories in CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: cmake

I have source files in src, headers in include and few files in tests directory. The main function (in src) is calling functions which are defined in file from tests.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project(multiDirTest)
include_directories(include)
set(SOURCES src/app.c tests/test.c)
#file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.c") 
add_executable(hello ${SOURCES})
```

Two files are in different directories (src and tests).
How to make it work ?

Comment: Have you thought about creating two separate targets, one library target for src/app.c and one test executable target + test definintion for test.c?  You can then link the test target against the library.

Comment: No. only one target. Actually im just trying out sample example.
Here, test.c contains function defination which is called by app.c but both are kept at different places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried with an identical CMakeLists.txt file as yours.  The CMakeLists.txt file should be outside all those subdirectories. You can create a build directory out at that level as well, so you have directories

build
include
src
test

Then just issue

cd build
cmake ..

You should still have only one main, despite the two directories.  If you want to run tests, you can pass command line arguments into main to indicate to run the tests.  In other words, you do not necessarily need a separate main for testing.